\leaders\hrule centered?
I would like to center my \hrule by keeping the \leaders mechanism. Is it possible ?
\documentclass{article}

% Source : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130529/6880
\newcommand{\mysep}{
  \par
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}\smallskip
  \leaders\hrule width0.5\textwidth\vskip.75pt
  \smallskip\smallskip
}

\begin{document}

Bla, bla

\mysep

Bla, bla

\end{document}


You want \cleaders\vbox and inside the \vbox you can center a rule.
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\myseplen}
\setlength{\myseplen}{\dimeval{2\medskipamount+0.75pt}}
\newcommand{\mysep}{%
  \par
  \cleaders
    \vbox to \myseplen{
      \vfill\centerline{\vrule width 0.5\hsize height 0.75pt}\vfill
    }\vskip\myseplen
}

\begin{document}

Bla, bla

\mysep

Bla, bla

\end{document}


(Picture produced with showframe.)

Thanks for your TeX-knowledge sharing.

You want \centerline{\hss\leaders\hrule\hskip.5\hsize\hss}.
\documentclass{article}

\def\mysep{%
  \par
  \centerline{\hfil\leaders\hrule\hskip.5\hsize\hfil}%
  \medskip
}

\begin{document}

Bla, bla

\mysep

Bla, bla

\end{document}

